# Definition of signed measure

Tags: measure-theory

I am currently reading Folland real analysis. For the definition of signed measure on p.85, I am confused about the third condition for signed measure.

> If {$E_j$} is a sequence of disjoint sets in $M$, then $v(\cup_1^\infty E_j)=\sum_1^\infty v(E_j)$, where the latter sum converges absolutely if $v(\cup_1^\infty E_j)$ is finite.

I understand the absolute convergence is for rearrangement, but why  we do not need to worry about the infinite case. For example, what if $v(\cup_1^\infty E_j)=\infty$. I feel like rearrangement is still a problem in this case. Can anyone explain this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "rearrangement is still a problem in this case" - can you clarify?

Comment: @NoahSchweber When $v(\cup_1^\infty E_j)=\infty$, it is still possible to rearrange the RHS series to make it equal to some random value other than $\infty$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yeah, but I feel like the definition try to exclude the infinite case. It seems try to say that when the measure in infinite, there is no problem in RHS series.

Comment: I think the focus is not on the infinite part, it is more to ensure that the summation of measure of disjoint sets is absolutely convergent.

Comment: @copper.hat But is it possible to have some potential logical inconsistency in the further argument. For example, when I check $v=\mu_1-\mu_2$ is a signed measure ($\mu_1,\mu_2$ are positive measures), I have only checked the absolute convergence for finite measurable sets. I feel like there is a potential problem in the latter arguments.

Comment: @Zorualyh I actually have the exact same question as you. The discussion is a bit hard to follow, because it appears some comments were deleted. However, from what I understand, there is a "hidden" assumption that whenever $v(\cup_1^\infty E_j)=\infty$, then the sum is invariant under rearrangement. Is this the correct answer?

Comment: @NoahSchweber It looks like one of your comments was deleted. May I assume that you said something to the effect of: "If $v(\cup_1^\infty E_j)=\infty$, and if it were possible that rearranging $\sum v(E_j)$ gave  something other than $\infty$, then by definition $v$ would not be called a signed measure"?

Comment: @user56202 No idea - it's been more than a year, so I have no memory of what I said (you're right though that it looks like one of my comments was deleted - I suspect *I* deleted it, intending to expand on it, and then forgot to do so).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I see, thank you anyway for your reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signed measure $\nu$ is defined to have the property that for disjoint sets $\{E_n\}$ in $\mathcal M$, the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu(E_n)$ converges absolutely if $\nu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right)<\infty$; this property is not true in general for  functions $\mu:\mathcal M\to[-\infty,\infty]$ such that $\mu(\varnothing)=0$ and $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(E_n)$ for disjoint $E_n$.

As for the case where $\nu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right)=\infty$, it is impossible to have a rearrangement $\sigma:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty E_{\sigma(n)}<\infty$, as this would imply $\nu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_{\sigma(n)}\right)<\infty$. But $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_{\sigma(n)}$, so $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_{\sigma(n)}=\infty$.

Comment: so does it mean the key idea for the third axiom is invariance under rearrangement and the absolute convergence is just a consequence of this? I am kind of confused whether the absolute convergence stuff is a part of the axiom or not.

Comment: @Zorualyh The absolute convergence is indeed part of the axioms.

Comment: But we can't apply the argument above if we are only equipped with the absolute convergence. It seems we have to assume the invariance under rearrangement beforehand. And I think invariance under rearrangement can imply absolute convergence when the series is finite.

Comment: @Math1000 It seems to me like you are using the equality $\nu(\bigcup_1^\infty E_n) = \sum_1^\infty \nu(E_n)$ to show that the equality makes sense. Isn't this circular?